# python matplotlib x axis value by data point (mouse hovering) is empty after set_xticklabels

Tags: matplotlib

hi python matplotlib experts,

the following code shows two lines in a plot, xticks label is rotated 45 degree. when I hover mouse over any data point in plot, it shows coordinate at right-bottom-corner, such as x=aaaaaa,y=10
well, so far so good.

```
def display():
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.ylabel('memory in GB')
    x_values=['aaaaaa','bbbbbb','cccccc','dddddd']
    plt.plot(x_values,[10,15,20,25], color='blue', label='heap memory')
    plt.plot(x_values,[20,25,30,35], color='green', label='direct memory')
    plt.legend(loc="upper left")
    x_ticks=[i for i in x_values]
    plt.xticks(x_ticks, rotation=45, ha='right', fontsize=6)
    plt.show()
```

then i probed the following code. still same data, setup plot in a separate function.
as you can see in order to set rotation, set_xticks and set_xticklabels methods are both invoked. well, same as previous example plot shows two lines in plot. however when i hover mouse over any data point, x axis value becomes empty, such as x= y=20.

```
def display():
    x_values=['aaaaaa','bbbbbb','cccccc','dddddd']
    setup_axes(x_values, [10,15,20,25], [20,25,30,35])
    plt.show()

def setup_axes(time_series, heap_series, dm_series):
    ax = plt.subplot()
    ax.set_xlabel('time')
    ax.set_ylabel('memory in GB')
    ax.plot(time_series,heap_series, color='blue', label='heap memory')
    ax.plot(time_series,dm_series, color='green', label='direct memory')
    ax.legend(loc="upper left")
    ax.set_xticks(time_series)
    ax.set_xticklabels([i for i in time_series], rotation=45)
```

does anyone know what goes wrong? why x axis value becomes empty?

thanks & regards

FW

i couldn't figure out why previous code doesn't show x axis value.

Comment: Maybe you could remove `ax.set_xticklabels([i for i in time_series], rotation=45)` and just set `ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)`? Also, if `time_series` is already used in `ax.plot(time_series, ...)` there is no need to call `ax.set_xticks(time_series)`.

Comment: To set the tick alignment, things seem to be a bit complicated. See [this github issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13774) suggesting `plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right", rotation_mode="anchor")`

Comment: @JohanC, thanks. it works perfectly after replacing set_xticklabels with tick_params.